# android - dictionary to translate strings

Tags: android

I have a lot of String code values that come from server, and I want to translate this codes to strings.

I can get key and value (code : string) from server every week and store/update them.

What is the best way to store, update, and read/use this data, over whole activities of app?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the best way to implement this is using databases like [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following alternatives:

- Shared Preferences - a persistent key value store. You can write values, that are stored to files, that are accessible in the app context.
- Database - use the built-in SQLite instance or a third party DB of your choice. The data is persisted and also accessible from within the app context. Extracting the values may be a bit over complex for your case.
- Plain files in a custom format that fits your use case - you can create and store files that are private to your app and store and extract info from them. You will have to deal with the file format and operations in a custom way.

As a whole, fetching your string resources from the network is not a very good approach. In this way you have to deal with localisation and internationalisation in a custom way and can't use the built-in goodies provided by the Android OS.